# How to get a jQuery Plugin from their Plugin-Repository CDN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn

For a website with live "edit-in-place", first I get the jQuery library from the fastest CDN for free ...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

... and on top of that I need the Jeditable plugin, listed in the jQuery repository at jQuery on [this page](http://plugins.jquery.com/jeditable/)!

1. Is this plugin also hosted on Jquery CDN?
2. If not, whats the use of jQuery having a plugin in the repository without hosting the script?
   In other words whats the use of a plugin repository?
3. How to load a script directly from jQuery repository?
   `<script src="................................../jeditable.js"></script>`

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html
https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_jeditable

Comment: can get it from cdnjs https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jeditable.js. Wasn't a difficult google search to find either

Comment: then host it yourself

Answer (score 1):

I'm mostly using [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com) for common js things.

A search for [jeditable.js](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jeditable.js) gives you the link and the script tag for easy copy-pastin'.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jeditable.js/1.7.3/jeditable.min.js"></script>
```

---

1. Plugins are most likely not hosted on jquery CDN, because they are most likely not written by the people behind jquery.
2. Discoverability? Don't know how their plugin listing works, but may have been from users submitting their plugins for example. Actually hosting the plugins would add another level of unnecessary complexity. Especially if the goal is discoverability, i.e. an easy place for jquery new-comers to see what else might be possible.
3. I don't know how "cloudflare one day hosts something and otherday it doesnt work without notice". At least not with cdnjs, which has always worked for me. But if you're worried, just download the script and host it yourself instead...